# How do I increase the timer on a dropped bag?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I recently got a Nitrado server for *Ark: Survival Evolved*. I want to increase the timer on a dropped bag. Not a death bag; I have already increased that, as well as individual items dropped out of the inventory. But if I hit the drop-all button, the bag's timer has not been increased.

Does anyone know what line of code I can add to alter this item's decomp time?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `GlobalItemDecompositionTimeMultiplier` setting in the `/script/shootergame.shootergamemode` section of `Game.ini`.

[Here](https://ark.wiki.gg/wiki/Server_configuration#Game.ini) is a list of available settings.

And [here](https://server.nitrado.net/en-US/guides/configuration-of-an-ark-survival-evolved-server) is the Nitrado guide for configuring server settings.